# Oracle sequence issue - ORA-00001: unique constraint (SAMPLE.SYS_C0039752) violated using Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am using below code to generating the sequence, upon transaction commit it throws an unique constraint error from db and all the time its not happening.

While tracing the logs, the sequence which is used to insert the data was already used by another row(data in table).

Suppose using hbm files for this entity class its inserting correctly.

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="detailsseq", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator", parameters = 
                     {  @Parameter(name="sequence_name", value = "DETAILS_SEQ"),
                        @Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "hilo"),
                        @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1"),
                        @Parameter(name = "allocationSize", value = "1")
                     })
@GeneratedValue(generator = "detailsseq", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 30, scale = 0)
public BigDecimal getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

Application using hibernate 4.3 and orcale10g.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi, did you get any solution for this ???. I am facing this issue now in test environment, when we migrated from one host of db to another host. Please let me know if you have got any ideas.